# Simplest and fastest way to find rows in a large CSV

Tags: java, search, csv, filter

I have several CSV files and I need to load them and search for rows by column value.
Someone suggests to use OpenCSV project to load CSV. But I don't know if this is the best way.
Does OpenCSV provide some search/filter utility?

Is there a better way to do what I need?

Comment: Before talking about what API to use, are you expecting a large number of CSV records? because if that is the case, loading the records in memory for search would cause memory issues, as suggested in some answers below, loading the records to a DB would be more appropriate. Loading records and searching in memory would be much better if you are expecting low number of records.

Comment: @AhmadSaleh yes, the CSV file could be very large...

Comment: then I agree with @piokuc, you may want to load the CSV programmatically, this would be a straightforward task for any CSV API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSV files are too big to keep in memory and you don't want to resort to storing everything in a database first (this would be a tedious disk to memory to disk operation) then there is another approach nobody seems to have mentioned: streaming.

The approach would consist of reading a number of rows from the file, processing them and then discarding the ones that don't match your search. You could do this with the Apache commons FileUtils for example. It could be some of the existing CSV API's offer this, I haven't checked that.

Answer (score 3):

You can load the data from your CSV files into your favourite SQL engine, like e.g. MySQL or SQLite, and use SQL to filter conveniently and fast. This is a common task so databases have ready to use tools for importing data from CSV files, this is how you can do it in SQLite: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

Comment: Thanks I did import it to SQLite and works perfect filtering 1 million result very fast .

Answer (score 0):

Use an embedded database, separating CSV from search functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/csv/apidocs/index.html) will simply give you a 2-dimensional string array of values. I doubt any solution will give you something more than this (given no type/schema info in a CVS file) and I suspect a well-crafted loop over these results is all you need. That'll be the *simplest* and *fastest* (as requested).

If you want to do more, you can run up the standard Java-provided [JavaDb database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/index.html) in-JVM, load the results into that and perform SQL queries without an external datasource/service.

Note that memory may be a problem if you load a sizable CSV, but just how big are these ? Memory is *very* cheap these days.